# How to add a colored outline to barmekko bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with the color of the contour of the bars, I tried to add a black contour and it still appears the same, I tried to make a similar graph with ggplot2 but the mekko library is the one that best suits it, I tried adding the functions. `geom_bar()` or `geom_col()`
e.g.
`geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black")`
but there are no changes.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(gridExtra)
library(egg)
library(mekko)
library(lemon)
library(ggh4x)

plotq<- data.frame(product = c(51.7,65.5,6.9, 27.6,13.8),
                  profit_margin = c(24.6, 70.2,1.3 ,1.3, 0.5),
                  D= c(32.8,33.6,2.6,12.1,5.2),
                  revenue = c(51.7,65.5,6.9, 27.6,13.8))

NUMER <- barmekko(plotq, product, profit_margin,revenue) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8DFF47","#FF9BB1","#FF974C","#F1FF54","#BFFAFF"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.5))) + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0, "cm")) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))

GRAVIM <- barmekko(plotq, product, D,revenue)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8DFF47","#FF9BB1","#FF974C","#F1FF54","#BFFAFF"))+
  scale_y_reverse(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.5, 0))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))

ggarrange(NUMER, GRAVIM, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the `barmekko()` function does not allow for any customization one option would be to manipulate the returned `ggplot` objects directly to add a black outline like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(mekko)

NUMER$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour <- "black"
GRAVIM$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour <- "black"

ggarrange(NUMER, GRAVIM,
  nrow = 2,
  common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right",
  align = "v"
)
```

[image]

Comment: why do I get this error when trying to run the code? :
 Error in plot$plot_env : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Hm. Can't reproduce this issue. Yesterday someone else mentioned this error which I also wasn't able to reproduce. Perhaps a versioning issue? I'm using `packageVersion("ggpubr")` "0.6.0" and `packageVersion("ggplot2")` "3.4.4" on R 4.3.2

Comment: I have checked and I have the same version of R and libraries

Comment: Hm. You might try with patchwork instead of ggarrange: `library(patchwork); NUMER + GRAVIM + plot_layout(nrow = 2, guides = "collect")`

Comment: Thank you very much, I skipped the error that appears at the beginning, I ran ggarrange again and that's it, anyway I will also try this last method. Great job